# Python Parsing weird XML?

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces

I have this weird XML I am trying to parse, and after reading this, I am still having issues.

I am trying to parse the NIST CVE database, it only comes in XML.  Here is a sample of it.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<nvd xmlns:scap-core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2" xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1" xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0" xmlns:cpe-lang="http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0" nvd_xml_version="2.0" pub_date="2017-04-12T18:00:08" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/nvd/patch_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/nvd/nvd-cve-feed_2.0.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 https://scap.nist.gov/schema/nvd/scap-core_0.1.xsd">
  <entry id="CVE-2013-7450">
    <vuln:vulnerable-configuration id="http://nvd.nist.gov/">
      <cpe-lang:logical-test operator="OR" negate="false">
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/a:pulp_project:pulp:2.2.1-1"/>
      </cpe-lang:logical-test>
    </vuln:vulnerable-configuration>
    <vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/a:pulp_project:pulp:2.2.1-1</vuln:product>
    </vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
    <vuln:cve-id>CVE-2013-7450</vuln:cve-id>
    <vuln:published-datetime>2017-04-03T11:59:00.143-04:00</vuln:published-datetime>
    <vuln:last-modified-datetime>2017-04-11T10:01:04.323-04:00</vuln:last-modified-datetime>
    <vuln:cvss>
      <cvss:base_metrics>
        <cvss:score>5.0</cvss:score>
        <cvss:access-vector>NETWORK</cvss:access-vector>
        <cvss:access-complexity>LOW</cvss:access-complexity>
        <cvss:authentication>NONE</cvss:authentication>
        <cvss:confidentiality-impact>NONE</cvss:confidentiality-impact>
        <cvss:integrity-impact>PARTIAL</cvss:integrity-impact>
        <cvss:availability-impact>NONE</cvss:availability-impact>
        <cvss:source>http://nvd.nist.gov</cvss:source>
        <cvss:generated-on-datetime>2017-04-11T09:43:13.623-04:00</cvss:generated-on-datetime>
      </cvss:base_metrics>
    </vuln:cvss>
    <vuln:cwe id="CWE-295"/>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="VENDOR_ADVISORY">
      <vuln:source>MLIST</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/04/18/11" xml:lang="en">[oss-security] 20160418 CVE-2013-7450: Pulp &lt; 2.3.0 distributed the same CA key to all users</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="VENDOR_ADVISORY">
      <vuln:source>MLIST</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/04/18/5" xml:lang="en">[oss-security] 20160418 Re: CVE request - Pulp &lt; 2.3.0 shipped the same authentication CA key/cert to all users</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="VENDOR_ADVISORY">
      <vuln:source>MLIST</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/05/20/1" xml:lang="en">[oss-security] 20160519 Pulp 2.8.3 Released to address multiple CVEs</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="PATCH">
      <vuln:source>CONFIRM</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1003326" xml:lang="en">https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1003326</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="PATCH">
      <vuln:source>CONFIRM</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1328345" xml:lang="en">https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1328345</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="VENDOR_ADVISORY">
      <vuln:source>CONFIRM</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="https://github.com/pulp/pulp/pull/627" xml:lang="en">https://github.com/pulp/pulp/pull/627</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:summary>Pulp before 2.3.0 uses the same the same certificate authority key and certificate for all installations.</vuln:summary>
  </entry>
<nvd>
```

I am trying to parse it with ET, but I get some weird output...

Example, when I use this,

```
with open('/tmp/nvdcve-2.0-modified 2.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
for child in root:
     print child.tag, child.attrib
```

My output looks like this...

```
{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0}entry {'id': 'CVE-2007-6759'}
```

What makes it confusing, is if I want to iterate over it, I appear to need to do this..

```
for child in root.iter('{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0}entry'):
```

If I do that though, I have no idea what the children's children are, or what ever.

For example, I am trying to pull out the `vuln:cve-id`, and each of the individual `cvss:base_metrics` (score access-vector), `vuln:summary`, and `vuln:product`.

Basically, I am trying to download the "xml stream" from NIST website every hour and update it into a local mysql database so I have a local place I can make queries too when performing vulnerability assessment in my environment. Figuring out how to iterate over this XML stuff is confusing as hell. I wanted to try to convert it into JSON, but that seems like an unnecessary extra step with possible issues since there is no 1:1 XML/JSON conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, XML with namespaces has to be treated [a little differently](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces). Here's another solution that continues using the ElementTree API.

Working with namespaces in this library, where you see `vuln:summary` you need to look up the `vuln` namespace in the root element's `xmlns:vuln` attribute, and then refer to it as `{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4}summary`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('nvdcve-2.0-Modified.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
# default namespace is given by xmlns attribute of root element, still must be provided
for entry in root.findall('{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0}entry'):
    product_list = []
    metric_list = []
    # just use the element's id attribute
    id = entry.get('id')

    summary = entry.find('{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4}summary').text

    software = entry.find('{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4}vulnerable-software-list')
    if software is not None:
        for sw in software.findall('{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4}product'):
            product_list.append(sw.text)

    metrics = entry.find('{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4}cvss')
    if metrics is not None:
        for metric in metrics.find('{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2}base_metrics').findall('*'):
            # we don't know the element name, but can get it with the tag property
            metric_list.append(metric.tag.replace('{http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2}', '') + ': ' + metric.text)

    print(id, summary, product_list, metric_list)
    #save to database!
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I was not familiar with namespaces, first time working with XML and it was super confusing. Normally I only work with JSON.

Comment: one last question if I might,

How dould I go about getting, specifically, cvss:score? I know I can do metric_list[0], but what if instead of pulling all the base metrics, I want to pull just that one? Would I do another nested for loop?

Comment: Just look at the existing code. But replace `findall('*')` with the particular element you're looking for.

Comment: would that just be, for example, 'score'? I tried that but got no response. Once I get back I will have to try it again.

EDIT: Never mind, I figured it out, its with the full name space, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a **namespaced** XML document. Therefore you need to address the nodes using their respective namespaces.

The namespaces used in the document are defined at the top of the document, and mapped to so called **namespace prefixes**:

```
xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0"
xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2"
xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4"
...
```

So the prefix `vuln` is mapped to `"http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4"` for example.

The one without a prefix is called the **default namespace** - it applies to all nodes that don't use an explicit namespace prefix (like the root node `nvd` and the `entry` nodes).

---

So you either need to use fully qualified namespaces, or the appropriate namespace prefixes (which in your code, you can map *differently* than they've been mapped in the parsed document) to address these elements.

Below is an example of doing that using `lxml` (and XPath expressions):

```
from lxml import etree

NSMAP = {
    'n': 'http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0',
    'cpe-lang': 'http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0',
    'cvss': 'http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2',
    'patch': 'http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1',
    'scap-core': 'http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1',
    'vuln': 'http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4',
    'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
}


def normalized_tag(node):
    return node.tag.replace('{%s}' % node.nsmap[node.prefix], '')


root = etree.parse(open('nvdcve.xml')).getroot()


entries = root.xpath('//n:nvd/n:entry', namespaces=NSMAP)
for entry in entries:
    print "Entry: %r" % entry.attrib['id']

    # CVE ID
    cve_id = entry.xpath('./vuln:cve-id/text()', namespaces=NSMAP)[0]
    print "  CVE ID: %r" % cve_id

    # Base Metrics
    metrics = entry.xpath('./vuln:cvss/cvss:base_metrics/*', namespaces=NSMAP)
    print "  Base Metrics:"
    for metric in metrics:
        metric_name = normalized_tag(metric)
        metric_value = metric.text
        print "    %s: %s" % (metric_name, metric_value)

    # Summary
    summary = entry.xpath('./vuln:summary/text()', namespaces=NSMAP)[0]
    print "  Summary: %s" % summary

    # Products
    products = entry.xpath('./vuln:vulnerable-software-list/vuln:product',
                           namespaces=NSMAP)
    for product in products:
        print "  Product: %s" % product.text
```

**Output:**

```
Entry: 'CVE-2013-7450'
  CVE ID: 'CVE-2013-7450'
  Base Metrics:
    score: 5.0
    access-vector: NETWORK
    access-complexity: LOW
    authentication: NONE
    confidentiality-impact: NONE
    integrity-impact: PARTIAL
    availability-impact: NONE
    source: http://nvd.nist.gov
    generated-on-datetime: 2017-04-11T09:43:13.623-04:00
  Summary: Pulp before 2.3.0 uses the same the same certificate authority key and certificate for all installations.
  Product: cpe:/a:pulp_project:pulp:2.2.1-1
```

For more information on XML namespaces, see the [Namespaces section in the lxml tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) and the [Wikipedia article on XML Namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).

---

For more information on the XPath syntax, see for example the [**XPath Syntax**](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) page in the [W3Schools Xpath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).

To get going with XPath it can also be very helpful to fiddle around with your document in one of the many [**XPath testers**](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm). Also, the Firebug plugin for Firefox, or Google Chrome inspector allow you to show the (or rather, one of many) XPath for the selected element.

Comment: Ah good to know, thakn you. Didn't realize namespaces or what ever worked this way. Trying to work with the ET tutorial was confusing compared to this. Thank you!